# How can I navigate terminal output like a text file with Vim keybinding?

Tags: linux, terminal, vim, zsh

I use Neovim which has a really cool feature where if I type `:terminal` it loads a terminal emulator inside Neovim. The interesting thing about this terminal emulator is that at any time I can type CTRL-\ CTRL-N and navigate the output like I would any text file. This allows me to scroll up to some part of the output and copy the text to my clipboard.

I would love this ability in a regular terminal. Is there any way for me to do this? I use Zsh now but as much as I have looked I can’t find a way to get the benefits of navigating a terminal output like I would inside Neovim. Preferably I would like to be able to navigate with Vim commands.

Comment: this sounds like `tmux`'s *copy-mode*, which uses emacs-style keybinds but has a vi-style option.  by default copies go into tmux-internal buffers; some scripting might be able to dump the buffer(s) into the system clipboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll second the comment mentioning `tmux`. Like it's older cousin `screen`, this is a *terminal multiplexer*. That mean that you can have multiple shells inside a single physical terminal (emulator). Like Vim, tmux supports split windows, multiple tab pages, and a special *copy mode*, in which you can scroll back and capture text. You enter this mode via `<C-B>[`; Ctrl-B is the default *prefix key* that all tmux commands start with. (All of this is configurable, similar to Vim.)

As a Vim user, you probably prefer vi-style key bindings. Put this into your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# Use Vim key bindings.
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g status-keys vi
```

As for yanking to clipboard, you'll find configuration snippets that do that on the Internet. Or use the [tmux-yank plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank), best installed via a [plugin manager](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm).

#### Alternatives

`screen` should work just as well, I don't think it has as many power features, though. You could also use Neovim / Vim 8 itself as your terminal multiplexer. I haven't yet looked closely into the new terminal features, but I remember that it was suggested that Vim should be able to do lightweight terminal multiplexing, as an alternative for users who don't need the full complexity of `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) it's like 99% the point is vi navigation of the terminal and having a visual mode.

Comment: Looks cool. I'll give it a go thanks :)